# Delta link return 404 error

Tags: onedrive

Im try get file changes using this delta link in my account

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drives/ca338b43f405bc50/items/CA338B43F405BC50!646/delta?top=1000&token=aTE09NjM2NDIxNDEzODk3MDc7SUQ9Q0EzMzhCNDNGNDA1QkM1MCE2NDY7TFI9NjM2NDIxNDE2MTMwNTM7RVA9MTY7U0k9NzE7U0c9MTtTTz02O1BJPTM
```

It works good some time, but some time later this return 404 error:

```
"error": {
        "code": "itemNotFound",
        "message": "Item does not exist",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "96d01e55-2f58-45e1-8f78-4f1acae0686a",
            "date": "2017-09-28T14:43:03"
        }
    }
```

Why it's happend?

Why some time later its return 404 error, but early return 200 ok?
Ho i can get file changes for example, for this link?

Comment: Does the item with id `CA338B43F405BC50!646` still exist?

Comment: yes of course.......

Comment: The caller appears to be a different user than the owner of the drive - is it possible that access to `CA338B43F405BC50!646` was revoked? Just covering the simpler scenarios before drilling in too far :)

Comment: used only 1 user

Comment: can u check your logs request?